# Retain dynamic values from Dropdown list after page refresh in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, forms

P.S- There are some other answers regarding the same question, but they are not very clear to me

I have a form where a user selects Country, then States appear, then City. Since I am using Laravel form validation, the submitted. If there is any error, the page is refreshed, then the error messages show up under the respective input fields. But, every time the page refreshes (due to some errors), the values in the dropdown list of State and City vanishes. I want to retain those values. How do I do it?

Here are my codes

**Blade**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
   <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <!-- Sweet Alert -->
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

   </head>
 <body>
   @if(!(Auth::check()))
   <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-info">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
           <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact Us</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="login">Login</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link"href="new_user">Signup</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>

<div class="container pt-2">
<div class="row shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-info rounded text-center text-white">
 <div class="col ">
 
   <h2>New User Registration</h2>
 </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<div class="row  m-5 p-5 bg-light  text-info">
    <div class="col">


 <form class="form-group" method="post" action="recheck_form" autocomplete="off">

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('first_name') ? ' has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
 @csrf
<label for="fname">First Name:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}">
 <small class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('first_name') }}</small>
 
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('last_name') ? ' has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
<label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}">
 <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('email') ? ' has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
<label for="email">Email/Username:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
 <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</small>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('password') ? ' has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
 <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" >
 <small class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('password') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('confirm_password') ? ' has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
 <label for="confpwd">Confirm Password:</label>
 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" >
 <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('confirm_password') }}</small>
</div>


 <div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('mobno') ? ' has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
<label for="mobno">Mobile Number:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobno" value="{{ old('mobno') }}">
 <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('mobno') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<label for="dob">Date of Birth(in YYYY-MM-DD):</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}">
 <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="gender">Gender:</label>

 <br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female" {{old('gender')=="Female" ? 'checked': ""}}>
 <label class="form-check-label" for="Female">
   Female
 </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Male" value="Male"  {{old('gender')=="Male" ? 'checked': ""}}>
 <label class="form-check-label" for="Male">
   Male
 </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="gender" id="Other" value="Other"  {{old('gender')=="Other"?'checked':""}}>
 <label class="form-check-label" for="Other">
   Other
 </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
 <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('gender') }}</small>
</div>


 <div class="form-group {{$errors->first('address') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="address">Address:</label>
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="address">{{ old('address') }}</textarea>
 <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('address') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('country') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<label for="country">Country:</label>
<select name="country" class="form-control" id="countrylist">
      <option disabled selected>Select Country</option>
      
      @foreach($countryname as $key => $country)
       <option id="countryname" value="{{$country->countryname}}" {{old('country')==$country->countryname ?'selected' :''}}>{{$country->countryname}}</option>
       
        @endforeach
     </select>
   <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('country') }}</small>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group {{$errors->first('state') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" id="statelistdiv">
   <label>State:</label><br /> 
   <select name="state" id="statelist" class="form-control demoInputBox">
      <option readonly disabled>Select State</option>
    
    </select>
<small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('state') }}</small>
</div>

 <div class="form-group {{$errors->first('city') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" id="citylistdiv">
     <label>City:</label><br /> 
     <select name="city" id="citylist" class="form-control demoInputBox">
         <option readonly disabled>Select City</option>
       </select>
   <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('city') }}</small>
 </div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('pincode') ? ' has-error' : 'has-success' }}" >
 <label for="pincode">Pin Code:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pincode"  value="{{ old('pincode') }}" id="pincode">
 <small class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('pincode')}}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
 <label for="dt">Date and Time of Submission:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dt" readonly value=@php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); echo date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ") @endphp>
</div>


<div class="form-group text-center">
<input type="submit" id="send_form" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"><br>
<a href="login">Already Signed up? Login Here</a>
</div>

<script>
//SCRIPT GOES HERE.SEE AJAX PART FOR THE SCRIPT
<script>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>



@else

<script>window.location = "dashboard";</script>
@endif




</body>
</html>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(function(){
     viewStateList();
     viewCityList();
    });
   
 //     $('#statelistdiv').hide();
 // $('#citylistdiv').hide();
 // $('#pincode').hide();

  
function viewStateList(){
 var countryname = $('#countrylist').val();
 
     console.log("State Name for Country",countryname);

       if(!countryname){
         return;
       }
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           }
           });  
                $.ajax({
                       type:'GET',
                       url: 'get-states?countryname='+countryname,
                       success:function(response){
                         // console.log(response);
                         if(response){
                            // $('#statelistdiv').show();
                           $("#statelist").empty();
                           // If no State exists for a country
                           if(response.length==0){
                               $('#statelist').append('<option value="Unnamed State in '+countryname+'">Unnamed State in '+countryname+'</option>');
                             }
                            
                            // $("#statelist").append('<option>Select State</option>');
                            $.each(response,function(key,value){
                             console.log("States-> ",value);
                               $("#statelist").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
                             
                              
                               });
                         }

                      },
        

                }); //ajax ends

 
} //viewStateList ends

function viewCityList(){
var statename = $('#statelist').val();
  console.log("City Name for state",statename);
       if(!statename){
         return;
       }
        $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           }
           });  
       $.ajax({
                 type:'GET',
                 url: 'get-cities?statename='+statename,

                 success:function(response){
                   // console.log(response);

                   if(response){                  
                     // $('#citylistdiv').show();
                     $("#citylist").empty();
                      // $("#citylist").append('<option>Select City</option>');
                      if(response.length==0){
                       $('#citylist').append('<option value="Unnamed City in '+statename+'">Unnamed City in '+statename+'</option>');
                     }
                    
                      $.each(response,function(key,value){
                       console.log("Cities-> ",value);
                       
                         $("#citylist").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
                       
                         
                             // $('#pincode').show();
                     });
                   }
                     // $('#pincode').show();
                 },

   

          }); //ajax ends


} //viewCityList ends

$('#countrylist').change(viewStateList);
   

$('#statelist').change(viewCityList);

     


      


 

}); //ready fn ends
</script>
```

Some images

**Selecting** *Country*, *State* and *City* (before form submission)

[image]

After clicking `Submit`. (The validation kicks in, but the State and city don't have their old values)

[image]

Comment: You are using onChange event, for this you need to use onLoad event also

Comment: @sta Can you give some examples?

Comment: Hi Skumar, did my answer end up working for you?

Comment: I didn't try it. I am doing that now.

Comment: @JasonRoman I tried your method, and while it is populating the **State** with respect to the _(pre-selected)_ **Country Name**, the **City** list is still empty

Comment: The code you posted only shows updating State and not City so I cannot tell what the issue is. However, the concept should be the same (and you might need a `stateUpdated()` function and a similar process)

Comment: @JasonRoman I obviously tried this concept for city. It seems like, since the data obtained from State is dynamic (to get the respective City list), the form does not update itself with the City List.

Comment: Again the concept should work exactly the same - you might have to listen on State change instead though or manually trigger the event yourself or something along those lines.. Again without seeing your actual code I cannot help debug why that is happening

Comment: @JasonRoman I updated the question with full code, and _separated_ the **ajax** part from the **blade** for convenience

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223503/discussion-between-jason-roman-and-skumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing State/City values upon submitting the form with a page reload because those `<select>` fields are hardcoded as  `disabled/readonly` upon loading the page, and there is no corresponding action that triggers a change to the Country select.  You can trigger the State/City AJAX update not only when Country changes, but when the page loads. You would want to move your update logic into its own function, like so:

```
function countrySelected() {
  var countryname = $('#countrylist').val();
  if (!countryname) {
    return;
  }

  // update state and city here
  $.ajaxSetup({/* ... */});
  $.ajax({/* ... */});
}
```

Then you need to call this function both when the page loads, and when a Country is selected:

```
// update when country selected
$('#countrylist').on('change', countrySelected);

// update when page has loaded
$(function() {
  countrySelected();
});
```

This will make sure State/City are loaded properly even when the form has errors and the page reloads. The only issue with this approach is that if you already had State/City options selected, they will not be re-selected.

To fix that you could try a few things:

- get the list of states/cities when submitting the form with a country, and then populate the lists in your template just like you do with countries, auto-selecting the option that was already selected
- or you could add selected state/city values in JavaScript on page load and then have your `load/change` event use JavaScript to set those corresponding options to `selected` after re-populating via AJAX.

Comment: I tried this method, the dymanic values of states and cities **do not** change on reload, even after the country is pre-selected

Comment: I mean, even if the **Country** is pre-selected, the **State** and **City** values are empty

Comment: After you tried switching to my method above, did you check to see if the AJAX is being called on page load?

Comment: Yes. ajax request is called, but only if I change the value of the _country_ (to populate the **state** dropdown) or _state_ (to populate the **city** dropdown)

Comment: I updated my answer so that state/city are updated properly on page load, check it out